# how to get image from Json in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode

i'm a baby of xcode developer, and i really need a help. Below is one of my json data, that i have print in output, for the text i already got display into my screen, but now i'm trying to get the image from the server, and i don't know how to do it.

JSON :

```
  "MoviePhotoL" : "\/Data\/UploadFile\/cnymv-01_1.jpg",
  "MoviePhotoP" : "\/Data\/UploadFile\/cnymv-02_1.jpg"
```

XCODE:

```
     let userImage = iP["MoviePhotoP"] as? String
     cell.imageView.image = userImage (??????)
```

i know that String cannot be converted into UIImage, and i already try to convert it to NSData and convert the NSData to UIImage(data), but still not get the picture :'(.... can somebody please help me?? i really need some help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those paths seem relative to another source.
You need to generate or get an absolute URL that will let you access the image.

Right now you have a simple string and that's all, you can't convert this to data or image.
You need a string that you can put in a browser and load an image.
Once you're able to do that, you can load the image in your app.

---

Example:

```
func getImage(from string: String) -> UIImage? {
    //2. Get valid URL
    guard let url = URL(string: string)
        else {
            print("Unable to create URL")
            return nil
    }

    var image: UIImage? = nil
    do {
        //3. Get valid data
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: url, options: [])

        //4. Make image
        image = UIImage(data: data)
    }
    catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    return image
}

//1. Get valid string
let string = "https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/f2c/effi-1-1366221.jpg"

if let image = getImage(from: string) {
    //5. Apply image
    cell.imageView.image = image
}
```

---

NOTE: `Data(contentsOf:options:)` is synchronous and can reduce performance. The larger the image, the longer it will lock it's thread.
Generally you would do such intensive tasks in a background thread and update UI on the main thread, but... to keep this answer simple, I chose not to show that.

Comment: thank u for responds :), this paths I get it from json response, which is my project right now, means only the path of the image in server. what if I don't have any URL?

Comment: @RishaSyazwani You need an absolute `URL` to access the image. Talk to the backend devs and ask about it

Comment: @RishaSyazwani If you have a part of the url then... in my example, say it is `f2c/effi-1-1366221.jpg`. If I know that it's relative to `https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/`, then I can generate an absolute `URL`. This is what you could look into as well. Your target should be getting a valid `URL`. Now how you do it, is up to you.

Comment: let me try the code first, later I'll update to you ;)

Comment: @RishaSyazwani  I updated my answer. Added the part of applying  `image` on the `imageView`. Anyways, best of luck :)

Comment: I already get the images... Thanks again :), after 5 days struggling with this problem, I'm happy right now, thank you again :)

Comment: @RishaSyazwani glad to have helped. Also, if my answer helped then do accept/upvote